# Compose app crashes when scrolling with a mouse

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I'm using my own android app on desktop from time to time and whenever I scroll my mouse anywhere in the app - whether scrollable or not, it crashes on

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ACTION_HOVER_EXIT event was not cleared.

This seems to be the root cause of the crash

```
/**
 * If an [ACTION_HOVER_EXIT] event is received, it could be because an [ACTION_DOWN] is coming
 * from a mouse or stylus. We can't know for certain until the next event is sent. This message
 * is posted after receiving the [ACTION_HOVER_EXIT] to send the event if nothing else is
 * received before that.
 */
private val sendHoverExitEvent = Runnable {
    hoverExitReceived = false
    val lastEvent = previousMotionEvent!!
    check(lastEvent.actionMasked == ACTION_HOVER_EXIT) {
        "The ACTION_HOVER_EXIT event was not cleared."
    }
    sendMotionEvent(lastEvent)
}
```

(https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.ui/ui/1.4.0-alpha03-source/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AndroidComposeView.android.kt.html)

I do not explicitly declare `dispatchHoverEvent`, nor `dispatchTouchEvent` where the Runnable declared above is used.

I'm looking for any solution, temporary or not. Further information regarding the crash, and I'm curious whether it happens to anyone else and if so, is it perhaps a problem of certain version of a library?

UPDATE My dependencies are following:

```
androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01
androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2
androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.4
androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0
androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5
com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.46.1
com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48
```

Comment: What version of compose are you using? Also, note this google issue tracker, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196857015.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the Google Issue Tracker. There currently is an issue open that probably describes the same crash you are experiencing:

[Issue #314269723](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314269723)

You might want to star the issue to show the Google Team that this issue is relevant for more people. 
Also, if your stacktrace is the exact same as the one pasted in the issue, you could provide a comment there to tell them you are getting this stacktrace while scrolling with a physical mouse, maybe it helps them to further track down the issue. Otherwise, I'd suggest you to open a new Issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the bug report with google this has been fixed in the compose libs now.

```
androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.7.0-alpha03
androidx.compose.ui:ui-android:1.7.0-alpha03
androidx.compose.ui:ui-desktop:1.7.0-alpha03
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314269723